# Creating a Variable with StreamReader Split Results

Tags: vb.net

I've recently been exposed to vb.net scripting and I am having some trouble figuring out how to accomplish a task.  I'm supposed to create a program that will automate an end user process but right now it only works for one specific id(because I've hardcoded a value to make the script run).  I've scripted the use of StreamReader to loop through all the possible entries,  but I can't figure out how to put that result into a variable so the program will automatically read the id selected and proceed through the steps, then loop until all id's identified via StreamReader have been processed. I apologize if this has been asked before, I am not very familiar with the terminology.

```
Private Sub Form1_FormClosed(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.FormClosedEventArgs) Handles Me.FormClosed
    Application.DoEvents()
    End
End Sub


Private Sub Form1_FormLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    uxNote.Text = "Starting"
    Me.Update()
    RunApp()
    Me.Close()

End Sub

Sub RunApp()
    Dim b As New BostonWorkStation
    Dim myHandle As Long

    b.Shell_("C:\Software\Application.exe")
    b.Activate("AppCaption", True)
    b.Connect("AppCaption", enumStreamType1.stWindows)
    uxNote.Text = myHandle.ToString
    Me.Update()
    b.Wait(2)

    b.Pause("@378,423")
    b.Tab_("user")
    b.Enter("password")
    b.Wait(2)


    b.Shell_("C:\Software\Application2.exe")
    b.Activate("App2Caption", True)
    b.Wait(4)
    b.Connect("App2Caption", enumStreamType1.stWindows)
    uxNote.Text = myHandle.ToString
    Me.Update()
    b.Wait(4)
    b.Smart.Create("App2Caption@726,1088", -1024, -633, 0)
    b.Smart.Click(False, False)
    b.Wait(3)

    b.Activate("Patient Lookup", True)
    b.Connect("Patient Lookup", enumStreamType1.stWindows)
    uxNote.Text = myHandle.ToString
    Me.Update()
    b.Wait(1)
    b.Pause("@104,423")

    ProcessPatients(b)
    b.Enter("10001") 'hardcoded id this is where I would like a variable to pull in the value
    b.Wait(2)

    'some more code steps here specific to what should be done once patient id has been selected

End Sub

Sub ProcessPatients(ByVal w As BostonWorkStation)
    Dim record() As String
    Dim sr As New StreamReader("my path for csv or txt file")

    Do While sr.Peek > -1
        record = sr.ReadLine.Split(CChar("|"))
    Loop

    sr.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: *Never* use `End` either `Application.Exit` or `Me.Close` should do what you need. You don't need the `Form_Closing` event as you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine it would look something like this:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_FormLoad(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        uxNote.Text = "Starting"
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        RunApp()
    End Sub

    Sub RunApp()
        Dim b As New BostonWorkStation
        Dim myHandle As Long

        b.Shell_("C:\Software\Application.exe")
        b.Activate("AppCaption", True)
        b.Connect("AppCaption", enumStreamType1.stWindows)
        uxNote.Text = myHandle.ToString
        Me.Refresh()
        Application.DoEvents()
        b.Wait(2)

        b.Pause("@378,423")
        b.Tab_("user")
        b.Enter("password")
        b.Wait(2)

        b.Shell_("C:\Software\Application2.exe")
        b.Activate("App2Caption", True)
        b.Wait(4)
        b.Connect("App2Caption", enumStreamType1.stWindows)
        uxNote.Text = myHandle.ToString
        Me.Refresh()
        Application.DoEvents()
        b.Wait(4)
        b.Smart.Create("App2Caption@726,1088", -1024, -633, 0)
        b.Smart.Click(False, False)
        b.Wait(3)

        b.Activate("Patient Lookup", True)
        b.Connect("Patient Lookup", enumStreamType1.stWindows)
        uxNote.Text = myHandle.ToString
        Me.Refresh()
        Application.DoEvents()
        b.Wait(1)
        b.Pause("@104,423")

        ProcessPatients(b)

        Me.Close()
    End Sub

    Sub ProcessPatients(ByVal w As BostonWorkStation)
        Dim ID As String
        Dim record() As String
        Dim sr As New StreamReader("my path for csv or txt file")

        Do While Not sr.EndOfStream
            record = sr.ReadLine.Split(CChar("|"))

            ID = record(0) ' <-- grab your "ID" from somewhere in "record" 

            w.Enter(ID)
            w.Wait(2)

            'some more code steps here specific to what should be done once patient id has been selected

        Loop
        sr.Close()
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thank you Idle_Mind! Your suggestions were very helpful! :)